# Identifier 'setValues' has already been declared"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am learning to program and I have come across this problem in which I cannot get the other script to work, I have tried calling them from a directory but it did not work either.
If I run them separately if they work but together they don't. I have renamed the variable but it doesn't seem to work either

Could they help me to know why one of the scripts doesn't work?

```js
const tiempo = {
  "0": [159, 38, 18],
  "1": [453, 77, 35],
  "2": [22, 5, 3, 2]
};

const setValues = () => {
  const ti = document.getElementById("valores").value;

  document.getElementById("prestamos").textContent = tiempo[ti][0];
  document.getElementById("electrodomesticos").textContent = tiempo[ti][1];
  document.getElementById("internet").textContent = tiempo[ti][2];
};

// setting values initially
setValues();
const sampleData = {
  "0": [435, 234, 38, 84],
  "1": [55, 35, 30, 15],
  "2": [22, 18, 15, 6],
  "3": [12, 10, 10, 2],
  "4": [8, 8, 7, 1],
  "5": [4, 3, 2, 0]
};

const setValues = () => {
  const val = document.getElementById("selection").value;

  document.getElementById("new-orders").textContent = sampleData[val][0];
  document.getElementById("in-process").textContent = sampleData[val][1];
  document.getElementById("approved").textContent = sampleData[val][2];
  document.getElementById("rejected").textContent = sampleData[val][3];
};

// setting values initially
setValues();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="d-md-flex align-items-center">

  <div class="ml-auto d-flex no-block align-items-center">
    <div class="dl">
      <select class="custom-select" id="valores" onchange="setValues()">
        <option value="0" selected>Semana</option>
        <option value="1">Mes</option>
        <option value="2">Dia</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Row -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- Column -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="card bg-info">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="p-10">
          <h3 class="text-white box m-b-0"><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt"></i></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="text-white align-self-center p-10">
          <h3 class="m-b-0" id="prestamos">159</h3>
          <span class="text-white">Préstamos</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Column -->
  <!-- Column -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="card bg-success">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="p-10">
          <h3 class="text-white box m-b-0"><i class="ti-home"></i></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="text-white align-self-center p-10">
          <h3 class="m-b-0" id="electrodomesticos">38</h3>
          <span class="text-white">Electrodomésticos</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Column -->
  <!-- Column -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="card bg-secondary">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row">
        <div class="p-10">
          <h3 class="text-white box m-b-0"><i class="ti-signal"></i></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="text-white align-self-center p-10">
          <h3 class="m-b-0" id="internet">18</h3>
          <span class="text-white">Internet</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Column -->

</div>
<!-- End Row -->
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body p-b-0 p-t-0">
    <div class="d-md-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="ml-auto d-flex no-block align-items-center">
        <div class="dl">
          <select class="custom-select" id="selection" onchange="setValues()">
            <option value="0" selected>Préstamos</option>
            <option value="1">Electrodomésticos</option>
            <option value="2">Internet</option>
            <option value="3">TV cable</option>
            <option value="4">Portabilidad</option>
            <option value="5">Seguros odontológicos</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card bg-info">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div>
            <h3 class="card-title text-white">Nuevas órdenes</h3>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center text-white">
          <a href="JavaScript: void(0);"><i class="display-6 ti-check-box text-white" title="AMP"></i></a>
          <div class="m-l-20 m-t-5">
            <span class="display-4 font-medium" id="new-orders">368</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card bg-warning">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div>
            <h3 class="card-title text-white">En proceso</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center text-white">
          <a href="JavaScript: void(0);"><i class="display-6 ti-timer text-white" title="AMP"></i></a>
          <div class="m-l-20 m-t-5">
            <span class="display-4 font-medium" id="in-process">257</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card bg-success">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div>
            <h3 class="card-title text-white">Aprobadas</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center text-white">
          <a href="JavaScript: void(0);"><i class="display-6 far fa-thumbs-up text-white" title="AMP"></i></a>
          <div class="m-l-20 m-t-5">
            <span class="display-4 font-medium" id="approved">368</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Column -->
  <!-- Column -->
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card bg-danger">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex">
          <div>
            <h3 class="card-title text-white">Rechazadas</h3>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center text-white">
          <a href="JavaScript: void(0);"><i class="display-6 fas fa-thumbs-down text-white" title="AMP"></i></a>
          <div class="m-l-20 m-t-5">
            <span class="display-4 font-medium" id="rejected">368</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Column -->
</div>
```

Comment: `var x = 1; var x = 2;` - what's the value of `x`?  The second `const setValues` overrides/deletes the first.  Use a different variable name for the second script.

Comment: Changed variable name but didn't work